# Insert to mysql from json data with object more than 1

Tags: php, json

I have a **json data** like this:

```
[{"data1":"body1"},{"data1":"body2"}]
```

I want to insert `data1` to my database with this

**php code:**

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO data VALUES('$datadecode')");
?>
```

but data json is not always 2 array, How can I insert it all to my Database ?

Comment: you need to use `foreach or for loop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and loop over decoded array.

Use MySQL's multiple row insert.

```
<?php
$json = '[{"data1":"body1"},{"data1":"body2"}]';
$arr = json_decode($json, TRUE);
if (! empty($arr)) {
 $values = array();
 foreach ($arr as $elem) {
  $values[] = "('". $elem['data1'] ."')";
 }
 if (! empty($values)) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO data VALUES";
  $sql.= implode(', ', $values);
 }
}
echo $sql;
// Outputs
// INSERT INTO data VALUES('body1'), ('body2')
?>
```

Comment: why after insert to mysql it return 0 ?

Comment: Print and paste sql here.

Comment: after i print it return 1

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this :

```
<?php
$json = '[{"data1":"body1"},{"data1":"body2"}]';
$arr = json_decode($json);
if (! empty($arr)) {
    $val = array();
    foreach ($arr as $elem) {
        $val[] = ($elem['data1']);
    }

    $vlaues= implode(', ', $val);
    if (! empty($values))
        $sql = "INSERT INTO data VALUES ('".$val."')";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `json_decode` to decode the json into array. Use second parameter as true for associative array.

**PHP**

```
$json = '[{"data1":"body1"},{"data1":"body2"}]';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);
echo $datadecode = $arr['0']['data1'];
```

**Ourput:**

> body1

Now you can use this variable onto the query.